# Using different texture on Cube created with HelixWpf toolkit

Tags: wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I've a simply box as follows:

```
BoxVisual3D box = new BoxVisual3D();
box.Width = Convert(panel.Width);
box.Length = Convert(panel.Length);
box.Height = Convert(panel.Thickness);
box.Center = new Point3D(quotaX, quotaY, quotaH);

string matType = panel.Material == SvBaseboardMaterial.MDF ? "mv-pannello-mdf.jpg" : "mv-pannello-base.jpg";
box.Material = MaterialHelper.CreateImageMaterial(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"" + matType, UriKind.Relative)), 1, false);                        
viewport.Children.Add(box);
```

I would like to apply different texture on each side of the box. Any hints? there're lack of information on the project site

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TextureCoordinates on each side of your cube to sample different part of your image.

Comment: Quite tricky for me, there're no docs about it. Do you have an example?

Comment: Texture coordinate is not helixtoolkit specific, it is universal 3D graphics basics. There are plenty of documents online. When you use helixtoolkit meshbuilder to create a cube, it creates default texture coordinates, you only need figure it out which face uses which portion of the image.